# How to read Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException

Tags: c#, exception

I am writing a youtube upload software. Actually my question is generic here.

The `Google.GData.Client` produces an exception. But I don't know how to reach in order to write ?

I mean how do I access it ? I tried with E. but there is no `Google.Gdata`

**I need to access Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException.ResponceString**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `catch` clause to specify the type of exception (in your case, `Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException`) so that you can access its members.

```
catch (Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ResponseString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
 // your GDataRequest code goes here
 } catch  (GDataRequestException e )  {
  // your error code goes here
}
```